# How to kill dhcpcd?

Tags: networking, shell

The following command works perfectly to start DHCP:

```
# dhcpcd -p eth0
```

DHCP cannot be stopped once it is started. The following command does not work:

```
# dhcpcd -k eth0
```

It returns the following:

```
dhcpcd[4700]: sending signal 1 to pid 4086
dhcpcd[4700]: dhcpcd not running
dhcpcd[4700]: kill: Bad file number
```

Could anyone offer a tip on how to kill DHCP?

Comment: Is the pid **4086** a constant, or does it change?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman No.  I have just rebooted the device and run the command again.  The PID is 4043 this time.

Comment: If you have to include this in a script, this snippet may help you (it has to be ran as root): `var=$(ps | grep dhcp)`. Then, in a new line, do `kill $(echo -n $var | cut -d " " -f 0)`, and it should kill the process altogether.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Thanks a lot. It will do though it would be ideal to have one command to to this.  I can use PS to get the PID, then kill it. I have tested it, and it works.  Could you turn your comment into an answer that I can accept?

Comment: Doesn't `su -c 'killall dhcpcd'` work?

Comment: @Firelord I got "killall: not found"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A way to dynamically get the PID of the **dhcp** process, and kill it altogether, would be to run:

```
su
var=$(ps | grep dhcp)
kill $(echo -n $var | cut -d " " -f 0)
```

Specifically:

- line 1 asks for root permissions;
- line 2 assigns the output of `ps` (which lists the active processes), filtered by `grep` with the keyword **dhcp**, to the variable `var`;
- line 3 calls `kill` to terminate the value contained in the first field (`-f 0`) of the variable `var`, by telling `cut` to separate the fields with a whitespace (`-d " "`). Not coincidentally, the mentioned value corresponds to the PID of the process **dhcpcd**.

Comment: That would kill any process with "dhcp" in its name. Even `killall dhcpcd` would be a better choice.

Comment: @SimonRichter You are in error: since I make use of `cut`, only the first PID is a candidate for killing. You are encouraged to experiment with it yourself, if you don't believe the correctness of the answer.

Comment: "any" means "any of them", not "all of them". Specifically, it kills the one with the smallest PID, so e.g. if I have two Ethernet ports, and run `dhcpd` on one, and `dhcpcd` on the other, then the `dhcpd` is likely to be started first because it has higher priority during boot, and your command would kill that instead. Also, if `dhcpcd` has a high PID, the chance is high that you match the `grep dhcp` command itself, which has terminated by the time `kill` is called, so it would do nothing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with `awk` as well. The commands would be;

`su`

`kill -9 $(ps -e | grep dhcp | awk '{ print $1 }')`

**Details**

`su` to jump to root shell, `kill -9` to force kill `ps -e` lists all the processes in details, we pipe it through `grep dhcp` which only outputs anything from `ps -e` output to dhcp, then we pipe it through awk, the print $1 only prints the contents of the first field, which is the process id of dhcp. And kill will kill the process matching that process id.